# why the #tmpTable last row is null?

Tags: sql, temp-tables

When i use this code to get the bak filename,why the `#tmpTable` last row is null?

```
--Configure extension procedure the cmd_shell enable
        declare @backupfile_store_path varchar(200)
                ,@DynamicSql varchar(200)
        exec sp_configure 'show advanced options',1;
        reconfigure;
        exec sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell',1;
        reconfigure;
        if (OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#tmpTable') is not null)
        drop table #tmpTable --#tmpTable
        --select OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#tmpTable')

    create table #tmpTable
    (
        DBName varchar(200)
    )       
    set @backupfile_store_path='E:\20131015'
    /*using extended procedure xp_cmdshell to get the path and name*/
    set @DynamicSql='cd /d "'+@backupfile_store_path+'"&&dir /a /b /s *.bak'
    insert into #tmpTable exec xp_cmdshell @DynamicSql
    select * from #tmpTable
```

When i use this command:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>cd /d e:\20131015

e:\20131015>dir /a /b /s *.bak>>c:\a.txt

e:\20131015>
```

The txt file's last row has a blank column,why it has a blank column?

Comment: wow that's some trickery going on in here. Well see what your dir and shell commands return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is about the windows `dir` commmand,the last output is a blank line.